# can't add up the int values from the query

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I have a mysql query that reads some records from a database table. the fields $key->r4, $key->sr13 and $key->huawei are perfectly displayed but I can not get the sum of the three.
here is my code:

```
$total_r4=0;$total_sr13=0;$total_huawei=0;
    foreach($view_data->result() as $key){
        $total_r4       += $key->r4;
        $total_sr13     += $key->sr13;
        $total_huawei   += $key->huawei;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$key->date";
        echo "<td>$key->time";
        echo "<td>$key->r4";
        echo "<td>$key->sr13";
        echo "<td>$key->huawei";
        echo "<td>".$key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei;

    }
```

The problem is actually in the last line where the 3 variables are not SUMed!

Comment: try this: echo "<td>".($key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei);

Comment: Ohh. thank you exculuber..! Me fool

Comment: And don't forget to close the `TD` with `</td>` markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
...
$total_r4       += $key->r4;
$total_sr13     += $key->sr13;
$total_huawei   += $key->huawei;
$tdTotal = ($key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei);
.....
echo "<td>".$tdTotal."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), both the `.` string concatenation operator and the `+` arithmetic addition operator have the same precedence.  Since they are left-associative, they are evaluated from left to right; therefore your current expression is evaluated as:

```
echo (("<td>".$key->r4) + $key->sr13) + $key->huawei;
```

To force an alternative evaluation order, either use explicit parentheses:

```
echo "<td>". ($key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei);
```

Or else do not use string concatenation, instead preferring multiple parameters to the `echo` statement:

```
echo "<td>", $key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei;
```

Note that this second approach is more efficient as PHP does not need to build the concatenated string in-memory.  One can also avoid unnecessary parsing of the double-quoted string literal by using single quoted literals where variable expansion is not required:

```
echo '<td>', $key->r4 + $key->sr13 + $key->huawei;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the sum using PHP, but don't forget to convert the data using [`inval`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.intval.php) or [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.floatval.php)

```
echo "<td>".(intval($key->r4) + intval($key->sr13) + intval($key->huawei))."</td>;
```

**And don't forget to close the `TD` with `</td>` markup**

Comment: It would appear that `r4`, `sr13` and `huawei` are fields of the same `$key` row; therefore MySQL's `SUM()` aggregation function would be inappropriate (one could instead use the `+` operator in the select list, if so desired).